# Heat released at constant pressure and temperature and heat released at constant density and temperature

Tags: physical-chemistry, heat, temperature, pressure, density

> Is there a relation between heat released at constant pressure and temperature and heat released at constant density and temperature?

I was reading some books on propulsion and combustion, and the author suggests the following exercise:

the heat released of the reaction $\ce{H_2 + 1/2O_2 -> H_2O_{(g)} }$ at constant-temperature and constant-pressure is $q_{_{(P,T)}} = \pu{57.8 kcal}$.
**What is the heat released $q_{_{(\rho,T)}}$ of the reaction $\ce{ O_2 + 5N_2 + 2H_2 -> 2H_2O + 5N_2 }$ at constant-temperature and constant-density?**

As a matter of fact, I have been wondering: **what is the general relation between the heat released $q_{_{(P,T)}}$ at constant $(P,T)$ and the heat released $q_{_{(\rho,T)}}$ at constant $(\rho,T)$ for a same reaction $\sum  \nu_i C_i \rightarrow 0$ ?**

Comment: The relation would be too complex to be any useful. Furthermore it would be too reaction specific to generalize. It would depend on how the average molecular mass changes with progress in the reaction.

Comment: @NisargBhavsar And about this specific reaction, how can I calculate the heat released at constant $(\rho,T)$ ?